Can a unique factorisation domain have a largest prime?
Suppose $R$ is a UFD and $(R,\leq)$ is an ordered ring. Is it possible that $R$ has a largest prime element? Below is my attempt so far to answer this myself, though I'm still unsure what the conclusion is.
I first considered the number of primes in a UFD. All finite UFDs (in fact, all finite integral domains) are fields and therefore have $0$ primes. If $R$ is infinite, it could still be a field and have $0$ primes. If instead it were to have a non-zero but finite number of primes, then it would have finitely many prime association classes. Letting $p_1,...,p_n$ be representatives of the prime association classes and letting $p = \prod_{i=1}^n p_i$, then consider the set $S = \{rp+1 | r \in R\}$. None of the prime representatives divide any element of $S$, but as $R$ is a UFD, the only non-zero elements which aren't divisible by any primes are units, so $S$ is a set of units. It follows from $R$ being a domain that $|S|=|R|$, so there are infinitely many units and at least one prime. There are therefore infinitely many primes, as each prime association class is infinite, though there may only be finitely many prime association classes.
So any UFD has either $0$ primes or infinitely many primes (overall, not up to association). Clearly UFDs containing $0$ primes have no largest prime. In the integers, the infinitude of primes is enough to guarantee that there is no largest prime, but in a general UFD there could primes arbitrarily close together, so the infinitude of primes isn't sufficient to prevent the existence of a largest prime.
Next, suppose $R$ is a UFD which has a largest prime, then it also must have a largest unit $u$. If $u$ were negative, then $u \leq -u$, so the largest unit must be positive. If $0 < u < 1$, then $u \leq u^{-1}$, so $1 \leq u$. If $1 < u$, then $u < u^2$, so we must have that the largest unit is $1$. From similar reasoning, one can conclude that the only units in $R$ are $\pm 1$.
Each prime association class therefore contains a positive and negative prime for each prime in $R$. We'll choose the positive primes as our representatives. Then suppose all primes were less than $1$. Clearly $2$ couldn't factor as a unit and a product of primes, so we must have a prime $p > 1$. Suppose there were only finitely many primes greater than $1$, say $p_1,...,p_n$. Then consider $x = 1+\prod_{i=1}^n p_i$. Clearly $x$ is bigger than $1$, yet isn't divisible by any primes bigger than $1$, a contradiction. So in fact $R$ must contain infinitely many primes greater than $1$.
I'm not sure where to go from here though. It still appears possible that $R$ could have an infinite descending chain of primes, all bigger than 1, which get arbitrarily close together. But it seems difficult to actually construct an example, as one would still need to be able to factor all integers into such primes. Moreover, I've been able to prove that $R$ cannot contain any rationals besides the integers, as well as prove that $R$ doesn't contain certain algebraic irrationals like $\sqrt{2}$. But it seems difficult to see a way to exclude enough kinds of elements to rule out the existence of $R$, or to show that $R$ is isomorphic to some obvious UFD like the integers, when $R$ could contain many transcendental elements.

It's not quite true that a UFD has either no (non-trivial) primes or infinitely-many. E.g., the usual integers, localized at/away-from a prime $p$ has primes ($0$ and the image of) $p$. I suspect you're not saying what you mean...

What do you mean by non-trivial primes? I prove that there are either 0 or infinitely many primes. I argue that if there are a non-zero but finite number of primes up to association, then there are infinitely many units. You can then multiply any prime by the set of units to obtain an infinite set of primes. I'm not saying that there are infinitely many primes up to association, merely that there are infinitely many prime elements.

Ah, my apologies! I did indeed think you meant "up to association..." etc. Might be worthwhile to emphasize this, since quite a few people may naturally (?!?) assume you meant "up to association...".

I edited the question for clarity.
